How to solve error 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE in Spring?
In my Spring web application I have a method which expects an excel file. It is sent to my RESful API as a parameter of the request. The media type is set to MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/personal-info")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public class PersonalInfoController {

    private final PersonalInfoService personalInfoService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadPersonalInfo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
            this.personalInfoService.seedPersonalInfo(file);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("File uploaded and database seeded successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}

The React client sending the request looks like this:
export const uploadPersonalInfo = async (file) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);

  await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/personal-info/upload`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${authenticationService.getToken()}`
    }
  });
};

I do not explicitly set the content type in the headers because I let the browser do this automatically. The logs look like this:
2024-09-01T10:40:03.906+03:00 DEBUG 18504 --- [VotingSystem] [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing OPTIONS /api/personal-info/upload
2024-09-01T10:40:03.911+03:00 DEBUG 18504 --- [VotingSystem] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/personal-info/upload
2024-09-01T10:40:03.917+03:00 DEBUG 18504 --- [VotingSystem] [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.has_voted,
        u1_0.password,
        u1_0.personal_info_id,
        u1_0.role 
    from
        users u1_0 
    where
        u1_0.email=?
2024-09-01T10:40:03.919+03:00 DEBUG 18504 --- [VotingSystem] [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        pi1_0.id,
        pi1_0.egn,
        pi1_0.first_name,
        pi1_0.id_number,
        pi1_0.last_name,
        pi1_0.middle_name,
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.has_voted,
        u1_0.password,
        u1_0.role 
    from
        personal_infos pi1_0 
    left join
        users u1_0 
            on pi1_0.id=u1_0.personal_info_id 
    where
        pi1_0.id=?
2024-09-01T10:40:03.925+03:00 DEBUG 18504 --- [VotingSystem] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /api/personal-info/upload
2024-09-01T10:40:03.926+03:00 DEBUG 18504 --- [VotingSystem] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/api/personal-info/upload", parameters={}
2024-09-01T10:40:03.927+03:00  WARN 18504 --- [VotingSystem] [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type is not supported]
2024-09-01T10:40:03.927+03:00 DEBUG 18504 --- [VotingSystem] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
2024-09-01T10:40:03.927+03:00 DEBUG 18504 --- [VotingSystem] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2024-09-01T10:40:03.929+03:00 DEBUG 18504 --- [VotingSystem] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-09-01T10:40:03.929+03:00 DEBUG 18504 --- [VotingSystem] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access

I tried changing the CORS configuration since at first I thought that there might be an issue with it. It hasn't solved the issue and so far I am using this configuration:
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}

Also, it cannot be a missing dependency or a multipart configuration issue since I have set all the constraints properly:
    servlet:
        multipart:
            enabled: true
            max-file-size: 10MB
            max-request-size: 10MB
            file-size-threshold: 10MB


when you don't set Content-Type header it defaults to applicaiton/json.  Since your endpoint doesn't consume json you get 415. Add to your headers 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'. Afterwards check in the network tab that the correct content-type header was sent
